# Getting the actual link URL from a Watir::Anchor object

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I have written code with Watir-WebDriver to get links from a table:

```
data.rows.each { |row|
puts row.cell(:index => 2).link
}
```

It returns this when I build it:

```
#<Watir::Anchor:0x007fc0f24b6aa8>
```

How do I get an actual URL from it?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
data.rows.each {|row| p row.cell(:index => 2).link.href}
```

More information at http://watir.github.io/watir-webdriver/doc/Watir/Anchor.html

Comment: Hmmm... It did not work. I saw that page recently actually, I am pretty new at this though so I don't quite understand what it is saying. All I know are that there a methods on the page. I've searched high and low, any other suggestions?

Comment: "Did not work" is not enough information. You have to be more explicit.

Comment: I am getting an "unable to locate element, using {:tag_name=>"a"}" error... I used xpath to put the table in the code. I read that you don't need to use xpath with watir-webdriver, but I don't know what else I would use. Is it because I am using xpath?